# how to fix misaligned swap

Tags: 20.04, swap

```
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

mkswap: warning: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 is misaligned.
setting up swap space version 1, size is 980 MiB
no label.

How to fix?

Comment: I believe this is just a warning, can you show the output of `lsblk --topology`?